# SimpleDateFormat parsing returns null

Tags: java, android, json, date

I have a date value of the type "2013-03-28T15:16:58.000Z". I want to convert it to "dd-MMM-yyyy" format. For that, I have used the following code:

```
public static String getTime(String time)
{
    try 
    {           
        String tim = time.replace("T", " ");
        SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);

        return df2.format(df1.parse(tim));
    }
    catch (ParseException e) 
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I got this solution from a variety of posts here in StackOverflow. But this code still returns null. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `null` value is being returned from exception block due the first `SimpleDateFormat` returning `null` as a result of an invalid date format.

The `Z`pattern is used to denote timezone patterns. To accept a literal `Z` character, you need to surround the character with single quotes.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
```

Also, you can do the same with the `T` character if you don't wish to do a manual replace:

Instead of

```
String tim = time.replace("T", " "); // remove
```

just use `time` and use:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is returning null because it is catching a ParseException and you are telling it to return null.  You should be at least print out the stacktrace and that should tell you why you are getting the ParseException.

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing a ParseException parsing the string 2013-03-28 15:16:58.000Z.

Try getting rid of the Z [like you did with the T] and using a `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US)`

Comment: Or try treating both Z and T properly like the question below, but with the following addition  `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);`